# Why and where do we implement session time out in Web Applications?

Tags: javascript, ajax, session

Is it because you have limited space to store session information of a logged in user or security concerns of allowing a user to be logged in for an extended time period, or probably a mix of both?

Is this done at the back-end or front-end?

Assuming it is a back-end requirement, I have seen lot of Javascript codes that creates a widget alerting the end user of a time-out. However I don't see how it can be really coherent with the server other than a guideline that says you haven't performed an Ajax operation for a certain amount of time and hence your session will be timed out without really checking back-end, because if you are checking back-end then you are actually extending you session.

Also in general, what is the criteria that extends the session of a logged in user? Does he have to fire an Ajax request to the back-end (assuming a SPA) or is it enough if he clicks on an input field? If so we do we keep a timer that gets cleared each time this happens? (Again not really coherent with the server but works practically). I know this is a broad question. Any pointers would be helpful.

[PS: If it is more about theory, I could just move to another site in the SO Network? I thought it is a relevant question for beginners.]

Comment: the server should always have the ultimate say. never trust the client

Comment: so clients are usually a user friendly way of alerting the end user? probably by maitaining a timer which isn't exactly the same as the back-end?

Comment: Basically you already got it.

Comment: Ok thanks that is re-assuring. I hope it helps someone who has a similar doubt. Because I searched a lot on the net for this and didn't see why do we need this in the first place. Any pointers would be helpful.